# Double title bar issue iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have noticed that whenever a phone call comes in while my app is in use (Or I simulate in-call status bar using the simulator), and the phone call ends, I end up with a double status bar in my app. The status bar goes away if I click any other tab and come back to the original tab (my app has a UITTabBar in it).

I have tried so many options that I am losing track now. The most I have read are to set your UIView's size to be flexible in interface builder but nothing seems to work.

Please look at the screenshots. I am pasting a default view of the sizing options in interface builder but believe me I have tried every single configuration option there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some heavy compute-bound processing taking place on the main thread? The main  thread should be dedicated to UI updates, with non-UI stuff kicked off onto separate threads.

Comment: No. Every single computational operation iuncluding API calls are done in separate threads using PerformSelectorInBackground